# How to use back references in kotlin regular expressions?

Tags: regex, kotlin

I'm trying to use a regular expression with back references in kotlin to replace the placeholders of a String in the following fashion:

> Source: "This is a %s with %02d whatever"
>
> Target: "This is a <s/> with <02d/> whatever"

So I'm looking for something like this but with a proper syntax, of course:

```
private fun escapePlaceHolders(text: String): String {
    return """%([^ ]+?)""".toRegex().replace(text, "<\1/>")
}
```

Obviously this code doesn't even compile, let alone work. The problem is that I do not know how to use the back reference in the replace function, if it can be done at all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may use

```kotlin
val text = "This is a %s with %02d whatever"
val rx = """%(\d*[a-z])""".toRegex()
println(text.replace(rx, "<$1/>")) // => This is a <s/> with <02d/> whatever
```

If you need to perform extra actions on the group value before replacing, aka "pass the backreference to a function" (e.g. to upper- or lowercase the value), you can use an overload of the `.replace` method with the *`transform`* argument:

```kotlin
// To get the same result as above, i.e. wrap Group 1 with < >:
println(rx.replace(text) { "<${it.groupValues[1].uppercase()}>" })
// =>  This is a <S> with <02D> whatever
// If you just want to turn Group 1 value to upper case:
println(rx.replace(text) { it.groupValues[1].uppercase() })
// => This is a S with 02D whatever
```

See the [Kotlin demo #1](https://rextester.com/VXKXP95840) and [Kotlin demo #2](https://ideone.com/s23GTf).

**Details**

- `%` - a `%` char
- `(\d*[a-z])` - Group 1 (later referred to with `$1` from the replacement pattern):

  - `\d*` - 0+ digits
  - `[a-z]` - a lowercase ASCII letter.

Feel free to adjust the pattern to your input, the idea remains the same.

Comment: Many thanks. My regular expression was wrong too. It worked fine for %s but failed with %02d for some reason.

Comment: @FranMarzoa Your `([^ ]+?)` matched only a single non-space char. You could try with `([^ ]+)`. But I suspect it would match too much.

Comment: It shouldn't if you put an space after it, I think. But anyway, yours works perfectly and it's really simple, so thank you very much.

Comment: Well, just for the sake of testing, it does work without the ? as you suggested.
https://rextester.com/WHT29374

Comment: Sure, lazily quantified patterns at the end of a regex always match the least amount of chars: `*?`/`??` match no chars, and `+?` matches one char.

Answer (score 9):

The simplest way to do that is what [Wiktor Stribiżew described in the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52859337/2196460).

There's a powerful alternative in case you need to not just reference but arbitrarily transform the matches for replacement, the [`replace` overload](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/replace.html) with the signature:

`fun CharSequence.replace(regex: Regex,  transform: (MatchResult) -> CharSequence): String`

It can be used as follows:

```
"""%([^ ]+)""".toRegex().replace(text) { "<${it.groupValues[1]}/>" }
```